# fix the minimum and maximum values of the colour bar legend

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I intend to plot a contour map with the data presented as an image. The legend of the plot truncates the maximum and the minimum values. However if am plotting other data there seems not to be any error.

This is my code:

```
a= xlsread('hour2045.xlsx');

 adms=a;
 y = adms(:,1);
 x = adms(:,2);
 T = adms(:,3);
xlin = linspace(min(x),max(x));  
ylin = linspace(min(y),max(y));

[A,B] = meshgrid(xlin,ylin);

Ta = griddata(x,y,T,A,B,'cubic');
[c,h] = contourf(A,B,Ta);
colormap(jet),colorbar;
xlabel('Drop Diameter')
cbl = colorbar;

xlabel(cbl,'Log(N)')
ylabel('Height (meters)')
```

Below is a sample of the data:

```
       H    D   LOG N
160 1.49508834  4.176091259
160 1.49508834  4.041392685
160 1.49508834  3.716003344
160 1.49508834  3.397940009
160 1.49508834  3.079181246
160 1.49508834  2.698970004
160 1.49508834  2.531478917
160 1.49508834  2.568201724
160 1.49508834  2.477121255
160 1.49508834  2.380211242
160 1.49508834  2.380211242
160 1.49508834  2.301029996
160 1.49508834  2.176091259
160 1.49508834  2.079181246
160 1.49508834  2.041392685
160 1.49508834  2.079181246
160 1.49508834  2.079181246
160 1.49508834  2.041392685
160 1.49508834  1.986771734
160 1.49508834  1.880813592
160 1.49508834  1.748188027
160 1.49508834  1.612783857
160 1.49508834  1.51851394
160 1.49508834  1.431363764
160 1.49508834  1.301029996
160 1.49508834  1.113943352
160 1.49508834  0.95708026
160 1.49508834  0.804003055
160 1.49508834  0.656385719
160 1.49508834  0.484299839
160 1.49508834  0.2757719
160 1.49508834  0.056523724
160 1.49508834  -0.159893906
160 1.49508834  -0.391473966
160 1.49508834  -0.623423043
160 1.49508834  -0.899629455
160 1.49508834  -1.244125144
160 1.49508834  -1.568636236
160 1.49508834  -1.886056648
160 1.49508834  -2.301029996
160 1.49508834  -3
160 1.49508834  -3
320 1.336228754 4.908485019
320 1.336228754 4.662757832
320 1.336228754 4.342422681
320 1.336228754 4
320 1.336228754 3.72427587
320 1.336228754 3.431363764
320 1.336228754 3.230448921
320 1.336228754 3.176091259
320 1.336228754 3.079181246
320 1.336228754 2.982271233
320 1.336228754 2.880813592
320 1.336228754 2.763427994
320 1.336228754 2.62324929
320 1.336228754 2.544068044
320 1.336228754 2.51851394
320 1.336228754 2.491361694
320 1.336228754 2.462397998
320 1.336228754 2.414973348
320 1.336228754 2.322219295
320 1.336228754 2.176091259
320 1.336228754 2.041392685
320 1.336228754 1.886490725
320 1.336228754 1.748188027
320 1.336228754 1.612783857
320 1.336228754 1.477121255
320 1.336228754 1.322219295
320 1.336228754 1.113943352
320 1.336228754 0.904445041
320 1.336228754 0.701395269
320 1.336228754 0.492201451
320 1.336228754 0.243286146
320 1.336228754 -0.04431225
320 1.336228754 -0.355561411
320 1.336228754 -0.684029655
320 1.336228754 -1.004364805
320 1.336228754 -1.30980392
320 1.336228754 -1.677780705
320 1.336228754 -2
320 1.336228754 -2.301029996
320 1.336228754 -2.698970004
320 1.336228754 -3
480 1.251814444 4.908485019
480 1.251814444 4.662757832
480 1.251814444 4.342422681
480 1.251814444 4
480 1.251814444 3.72427587
480 1.251814444 3.431363764
480 1.251814444 3.230448921
480 1.251814444 3.176091259
480 1.251814444 3.079181246
480 1.251814444 2.982271233
480 1.251814444 2.880813592
480 1.251814444 2.763427994
480 1.251814444 2.62324929
480 1.251814444 2.544068044
480 1.251814444 2.51851394
480 1.251814444 2.491361694
480 1.251814444 2.462397998
480 1.251814444 2.414973348
480 1.251814444 2.322219295
480 1.251814444 2.176091259
480 1.251814444 2.041392685
480 1.251814444 1.886490725
480 1.251814444 1.748188027
480 1.251814444 1.612783857
480 1.251814444 1.477121255
480 1.251814444 1.322219295
480 1.251814444 1.113943352
480 1.251814444 0.904445041
480 1.251814444 0.701395269
480 1.251814444 0.492201451
480 1.251814444 0.243286146
480 1.251814444 -0.04431225
480 1.251814444 -0.355561411
480 1.251814444 -0.684029655
480 1.251814444 -1.004364805
480 1.251814444 -1.30980392
480 1.251814444 -1.677780705
480 1.251814444 -2
480 1.251814444 -2.301029996
480 1.251814444 -2.698970004
480 1.251814444 -3
640 1.282957027 4.505149978
640 1.282957027 4.447158031
640 1.282957027 4.255272505
640 1.282957027 3.903089987
640 1.282957027 3.653212514
640 1.282957027 3.491361694
640 1.282957027 3.230448921
640 1.282957027 3.146128036
640 1.282957027 3.146128036
640 1.282957027 3.079181246
640 1.282957027 2.973127854
640 1.282957027 2.892094603
640 1.282957027 2.812913357
640 1.282957027 2.785329835
640 1.282957027 2.755874856
640 1.282957027 2.681241237
640 1.282957027 2.579783597
640 1.282957027 2.477121255
640 1.282957027 2.361727836
640 1.282957027 2.230448921
640 1.282957027 2.113943352
640 1.282957027 1.973127854
640 1.282957027 1.84509804
640 1.282957027 1.707570176
640 1.282957027 1.544068044
640 1.282957027 1.361727836
640 1.282957027 1.113943352
640 1.282957027 0.849173633
640 1.282957027 0.58410497
640 1.282957027 0.34752516
640 1.282957027 0.063708559
640 1.282957027 -0.310691141
640 1.282957027 -0.739928612
640 1.282957027 -1.180456064
640 1.282957027 -1.657577319
640 1.282957027 -1.920818754
640 1.282957027 -2.15490196
640 1.282957027 -2.522878745
640 1.282957027 -3
640 1.282957027 -3
640 1.282957027 -3
800 1.350688721 4.785329835
800 1.350688721 4.568201724
800 1.350688721 4.301029996
800 1.350688721 3.959041392
800 1.350688721 3.748188027
800 1.350688721 3.544068044
800 1.350688721 3.278753601
800 1.350688721 3.176091259
800 1.350688721 3.176091259
800 1.350688721 3.079181246
800 1.350688721 2.959041392
800 1.350688721 2.892094603
800 1.350688721 2.812913357
800 1.350688721 2.755874856
800 1.350688721 2.72427587
800 1.350688721 2.681241237
800 1.350688721 2.602059991
800 1.350688721 2.505149978
800 1.350688721 2.397940009
800 1.350688721 2.278753601
800 1.350688721 2.176091259
800 1.350688721 2.041392685
800 1.350688721 1.886490725
800 1.350688721 1.755874856
800 1.350688721 1.602059991
800 1.350688721 1.380211242
800 1.350688721 1.146128036
800 1.350688721 0.897242103
800 1.350688721 0.62838893
800 1.350688721 0.354300562
800 1.350688721 0.070407322
800 1.350688721 -0.278189385
800 1.350688721 -0.669586227
800 1.350688721 -1.102372909
800 1.350688721 -1.619788758
800 1.350688721 -2.045757491
800 1.350688721 -2.301029996
800 1.350688721 -2.698970004
800 1.350688721 -2.698970004
800 1.350688721 -3
800 1.350688721 -3
960 1.428898885 4.568201724
960 1.428898885 4.278753601
960 1.428898885 4.041392685
960 1.428898885 3.832508913
960 1.428898885 3.662757832
960 1.428898885 3.462397998
960 1.428898885 3.230448921
960 1.428898885 3.113943352
960 1.428898885 3.079181246
960 1.428898885 3.041392685
960 1.428898885 2.934498451
960 1.428898885 2.838849091
960 1.428898885 2.740362689
960 1.428898885 2.662757832
960 1.428898885 2.612783857
960 1.428898885 2.602059991
960 1.428898885 2.579783597
960 1.428898885 2.505149978
960 1.428898885 2.414973348
960 1.428898885 2.301029996
960 1.428898885 2.204119983
960 1.428898885 2.079181246
960 1.428898885 1.939519253
960 1.428898885 1.792391689
960 1.428898885 1.653212514
960 1.428898885 1.491361694
960 1.428898885 1.301029996
960 1.428898885 1.079181246
960 1.428898885 0.826139618
960 1.428898885 0.583878598
960 1.428898885 0.341830057
960 1.428898885 0.033423755
960 1.428898885 -0.324221658
960 1.428898885 -0.70333481
960 1.428898885 -1.180456064
960 1.428898885 -1.744727495
960 1.428898885 -2.22184875
960 1.428898885 -2.522878745
960 1.428898885 -3
960 1.428898885 -3
1120    1.502966673 4.176091259
1120    1.502966673 3.875061263
1120    1.502966673 3.698970004
1120    1.502966673 3.431363764
1120    1.502966673 3.301029996
1120    1.502966673 3.146128036
1120    1.502966673 2.919078092
1120    1.502966673 2.897627091
1120    1.502966673 2.897627091
1120    1.502966673 2.857332496
1120    1.502966673 2.799340549
1120    1.502966673 2.73239376
1120    1.502966673 2.662757832
1120    1.502966673 2.591064607
1120    1.502966673 2.531478917
1120    1.502966673 2.491361694
1120    1.502966673 2.477121255
1120    1.502966673 2.447158031
1120    1.502966673 2.397940009
1120    1.502966673 2.301029996
1120    1.502966673 2.204119983
1120    1.502966673 2.079181246
1120    1.502966673 1.934498451
1120    1.502966673 1.785329835
1120    1.502966673 1.633468456
1120    1.502966673 1.505149978
1120    1.502966673 1.361727836
1120    1.502966673 1.204119983
1120    1.502966673 0.990693961
1120    1.502966673 0.7846886
1120    1.502966673 0.574378564
1120    1.502966673 0.311753861
1120    1.502966673 -0.003926346
1120    1.502966673 -0.35261703
1120    1.502966673 -0.730487056
1120    1.502966673 -1.161150909
1120    1.502966673 -1.657577319
1120    1.502966673 -2.22184875
1120    1.502966673 -2.698970004
1120    1.502966673 -3
1280    1.567995715 4.414973348
1280    1.567995715 4.176091259
1280    1.567995715 3.832508913
1280    1.567995715 3.477121255
1280    1.567995715 3.230448921
1280    1.567995715 3.079181246
1280    1.567995715 2.944482672
1280    1.567995715 2.86923172
1280    1.567995715 2.770852012
1280    1.567995715 2.653212514
1280    1.567995715 2.633468456
1280    1.567995715 2.662757832
1280    1.567995715 2.633468456
1280    1.567995715 2.556302501
1280    1.567995715 2.462397998
1280    1.567995715 2.361727836
1280    1.567995715 2.322219295
1280    1.567995715 2.322219295
1280    1.567995715 2.342422681
1280    1.567995715 2.278753601
1280    1.567995715 2.176091259
1280    1.567995715 2.041392685
1280    1.567995715 1.913813852
1280    1.567995715 1.77815125
1280    1.567995715 1.633468456
1280    1.567995715 1.505149978
1280    1.567995715 1.380211242
1280    1.567995715 1.255272505
1280    1.567995715 1.113943352
1280    1.567995715 0.927934682
1280    1.567995715 0.727134424
1280    1.567995715 0.498172661
1280    1.567995715 0.209515015
1280    1.567995715 -0.149353765
1280    1.567995715 -0.540607512
1280    1.567995715 -0.954677021
1280    1.567995715 -1.431798276
1280    1.567995715 -1.958607315
1280    1.567995715 -2.522878745
1280    1.567995715 -3
1440    1.614216997 2.886490725
1440    1.614216997 3.255272505
1440    1.614216997 3.204119983
1440    1.614216997 2.954242509
1440    1.614216997 2.832508913
1440    1.614216997 2.698970004
1440    1.614216997 2.591064607
1440    1.614216997 2.591064607
1440    1.614216997 2.591064607
1440    1.614216997 2.591064607
1440    1.614216997 2.556302501
1440    1.614216997 2.505149978
1440    1.614216997 2.431363764
1440    1.614216997 2.322219295
1440    1.614216997 2.255272505
1440    1.614216997 2.204119983
1440    1.614216997 2.176091259
1440    1.614216997 2.176091259
1440    1.614216997 2.146128036
1440    1.614216997 2.079181246
1440    1.614216997 1.944482672
1440    1.614216997 1.819543936
1440    1.614216997 1.716003344
1440    1.614216997 1.591064607
1440    1.614216997 1.447158031
1440    1.614216997 1.301029996
1440    1.614216997 1.146128036
1440    1.614216997 0.991801799
1440    1.614216997 0.778585328
1440    1.614216997 0.543074235
1440    1.614216997 0.29380436
1440    1.614216997 -0.017276612
1440    1.614216997 -0.401209493
1440    1.614216997 -0.823908741
1440    1.614216997 -1.27572413
1440    1.614216997 -1.744727495
1440    1.614216997 -2.301029996
1440    1.614216997 -3
1600    1.580450942 3.913813852
1600    1.580450942 3.838849091
1600    1.580450942 3.278753601
1600    1.580450942 3.113943352
1600    1.580450942 3.079181246
1600    1.580450942 2.892094603
1600    1.580450942 2.77815125
1600    1.580450942 2.707570176
1600    1.580450942 2.662757832
1600    1.580450942 2.643452676
1600    1.580450942 2.591064607
1600    1.580450942 2.531478917
1600    1.580450942 2.477121255
1600    1.580450942 2.431363764
1600    1.580450942 2.380211242
1600    1.580450942 2.322219295
1600    1.580450942 2.204119983
1600    1.580450942 2.079181246
1600    1.580450942 2.041392685
1600    1.580450942 2.079181246
1600    1.580450942 2.113943352
1600    1.580450942 2.079181246
1600    1.580450942 1.954242509
1600    1.580450942 1.838849091
1600    1.580450942 1.740362689
1600    1.580450942 1.62324929
1600    1.580450942 1.462397998
1600    1.580450942 1.278753601
1600    1.580450942 1.146128036
1600    1.580450942 0.995679061
1600    1.580450942 0.805568818
1600    1.580450942 0.60129931
1600    1.580450942 0.374565061
1600    1.580450942 0.079543007
1600    1.580450942 -0.289882635
1600    1.580450942 -0.696803943
1600    1.580450942 -1.107905397
1600    1.580450942 -1.522878745
1600    1.580450942 -2
1600    1.580450942 -2.522878745
1600    1.580450942 -3
1760    1.593013751 3.880813592
1760    1.593013751 4.041392685
1760    1.593013751 3.707570176
1760    1.593013751 3.113943352
1760    1.593013751 1.748188027
1760    1.593013751 2.579783597
1760    1.593013751 2.832508913
1760    1.593013751 2.799340549
1760    1.593013751 2.716003344
1760    1.593013751 2.591064607
1760    1.593013751 2.51851394
1760    1.593013751 2.491361694
1760    1.593013751 2.447158031
1760    1.593013751 2.414973348
1760    1.593013751 2.397940009
1760    1.593013751 2.342422681
1760    1.593013751 2.204119983
1760    1.593013751 2.041392685
1760    1.593013751 2.041392685
1760    1.593013751 2.079181246
1760    1.593013751 2.113943352
1760    1.593013751 2.079181246
1760    1.593013751 1.963787827
1760    1.593013751 1.851258349
1760    1.593013751 1.755874856
1760    1.593013751 1.643452676
1760    1.593013751 1.505149978
1760    1.593013751 1.322219295
1760    1.593013751 1.146128036
1760    1.593013751 0.99550357
1760    1.593013751 0.814913181
1760    1.593013751 0.617419747
1760    1.593013751 0.372359583
1760    1.593013751 0.061452479
1760    1.593013751 -0.298432015
1760    1.593013751 -0.70333481
1760    1.593013751 -1.124938737
1760    1.593013751 -1.537602002
1760    1.593013751 -2
1760    1.593013751 -2.522878745
1920    1.657346542 3.886490725
1920    1.657346542 3.763427994
1920    1.657346542 3.568201724
1920    1.657346542 3.204119983
1920    1.657346542 2.924279286
1920    1.657346542 2.939519253
1920    1.657346542 3
1920    1.657346542 2.913813852
1920    1.657346542 2.763427994
1920    1.657346542 2.681241237
1920    1.657346542 2.643452676
1920    1.657346542 2.531478917
1920    1.657346542 2.414973348
1920    1.657346542 2.414973348
1920    1.657346542 2.431363764
1920    1.657346542 2.380211242
1920    1.657346542 2.255272505
1920    1.657346542 2.113943352
1920    1.657346542 2
1920    1.657346542 2
1920    1.657346542 2.041392685
1920    1.657346542 2.079181246
1920    1.657346542 2
1920    1.657346542 1.86923172
1920    1.657346542 1.73239376
1920    1.657346542 1.612783857
1920    1.657346542 1.477121255
1920    1.657346542 1.322219295
1920    1.657346542 1.146128036
1920    1.657346542 0.945862324
1920    1.657346542 0.735519059
1920    1.657346542 0.517327882
1920    1.657346542 0.263162465
1920    1.657346542 -0.032920266
1920    1.657346542 -0.355561411
1920    1.657346542 -0.730487056
1920    1.657346542 -1.161150909
1920    1.657346542 -1.619788758
1920    1.657346542 -2.096910013
1920    1.657346542 -2.698970004
2080    1.728820795 3.69019608
2080    1.728820795 3.342422681
2080    1.728820795 2.903089987
2080    1.728820795 2.838849091
2080    1.728820795 2.908485019
2080    1.728820795 2.792391689
2080    1.728820795 2.832508913
2080    1.728820795 2.763427994
2080    1.728820795 2.62324929
2080    1.728820795 2.591064607
2080    1.728820795 2.579783597
2080    1.728820795 2.462397998
2080    1.728820795 2.397940009
2080    1.728820795 2.397940009
2080    1.728820795 2.380211242
2080    1.728820795 2.322219295
2080    1.728820795 2.230448921
2080    1.728820795 2.079181246
2080    1.728820795 1.939519253
2080    1.728820795 1.851258349
2080    1.728820795 1.86923172
2080    1.728820795 1.929418926
2080    1.728820795 1.934498451
2080    1.728820795 1.86332286
2080    1.728820795 1.73239376
2080    1.728820795 1.579783597
2080    1.728820795 1.414973348
2080    1.728820795 1.255272505
2080    1.728820795 1.113943352
2080    1.728820795 0.905256049
2080    1.728820795 0.684396478
2080    1.728820795 0.454539985
2080    1.728820795 0.183554534
2080    1.728820795 -0.131943638
2080    1.728820795 -0.438898616
2080    1.728820795 -0.747146969
2080    1.728820795 -1.119186408
2080    1.728820795 -1.552841969
2080    1.728820795 -2.045757491
2080    1.728820795 -2.522878745
2080    1.728820795 -3
2240    1.733376148 3.929418926
2240    1.733376148 3.698970004
2240    1.733376148 3.69019608
2240    1.733376148 3.342422681
2240    1.733376148 2.929418926
2240    1.733376148 2.799340549
2240    1.733376148 2.77815125
2240    1.733376148 2.73239376
2240    1.733376148 2.579783597
2240    1.733376148 2.414973348
2240    1.733376148 2.342422681
2240    1.733376148 2.278753601
2240    1.733376148 2.255272505
2240    1.733376148 2.255272505
2240    1.733376148 2.230448921
2240    1.733376148 2.146128036
2240    1.733376148 2.079181246
2240    1.733376148 1.982271233
2240    1.733376148 1.86923172
2240    1.733376148 1.763427994
2240    1.733376148 1.698970004
2240    1.733376148 1.672097858
2240    1.733376148 1.69019608
2240    1.733376148 1.69019608
2240    1.733376148 1.633468456
2240    1.733376148 1.505149978
2240    1.733376148 1.342422681
2240    1.733376148 1.204119983
2240    1.733376148 1.041392685
2240    1.733376148 0.829946696
2240    1.733376148 0.6349808
2240    1.733376148 0.451325808
2240    1.733376148 0.238798563
2240    1.733376148 -0.037630664
2240    1.733376148 -0.333482019
2240    1.733376148 -0.619788758
2240    1.733376148 -0.946921557
2240    1.733376148 -1.301029996
2240    1.733376148 -1.698970004
2240    1.733376148 -2.15490196
2240    1.733376148 -2.698970004
2240    1.733376148 -3
2400    1.68820045  4.322219295
2400    1.68820045  4.041392685
2400    1.68820045  3.653212514
2400    1.68820045  3.146128036
2400    1.68820045  2.897627091
2400    1.68820045  2.748188027
2400    1.68820045  2.477121255
2400    1.68820045  2.380211242
2400    1.68820045  2.380211242
2400    1.68820045  2.322219295
2400    1.68820045  2.204119983
2400    1.68820045  2.146128036
2400    1.68820045  2.079181246
2400    1.68820045  2
2400    1.68820045  1.991226076
2400    1.68820045  1.991226076
2400    1.68820045  1.949390007
2400    1.68820045  1.875061263
2400    1.68820045  1.812913357
2400    1.68820045  1.740362689
2400    1.68820045  1.633468456
2400    1.68820045  1.51851394
2400    1.68820045  1.431363764
2400    1.68820045  1.380211242
2400    1.68820045  1.361727836
2400    1.68820045  1.322219295
2400    1.68820045  1.230448921
2400    1.68820045  1.113943352
2400    1.68820045  0.959709024
2400    1.68820045  0.774662923
2400    1.68820045  0.599555591
2400    1.68820045  0.405858399
2400    1.68820045  0.20790353
2400    1.68820045  -0.021363052
2400    1.68820045  -0.283996656
2400    1.68820045  -0.568636236
2400    1.68820045  -0.863279433
2400    1.68820045  -1.113509275
2400    1.68820045  -1.387216143
2400    1.68820045  -1.769551079
2400    1.68820045  -2.15490196
2400    1.68820045  -2.522878745
2400    1.68820045  -3
2560    1.61411616  4.301029996
2560    1.61411616  3.819543936
2560    1.61411616  3.602059991
2560    1.61411616  3.361727836
2560    1.61411616  3.204119983
2560    1.61411616  2.806179974
2560    1.61411616  1.875061263
2560    1.61411616  1.963787827
2560    1.61411616  2.041392685
2560    1.61411616  2.230448921
2560    1.61411616  2.230448921
2560    1.61411616  2.146128036
2560    1.61411616  2.041392685
2560    1.61411616  1.968482949
2560    1.61411616  1.903089987
2560    1.61411616  1.84509804
2560    1.61411616  1.812913357
2560    1.61411616  1.806179974
2560    1.61411616  1.755874856
2560    1.61411616  1.653212514
2560    1.61411616  1.544068044
2560    1.61411616  1.477121255
2560    1.61411616  1.397940009
2560    1.61411616  1.278753601
2560    1.61411616  1.176091259
2560    1.61411616  1.079181246
2560    1.61411616  1
2560    1.61411616  0.958898195
2560    1.61411616  0.880584956
2560    1.61411616  0.759441197
2560    1.61411616  0.586249639
2560    1.61411616  0.347915187
2560    1.61411616  0.128076013
2560    1.61411616  -0.034798299
2560    1.61411616  -0.22184875
2560    1.61411616  -0.465973894
2560    1.61411616  -0.725842151
2560    1.61411616  -0.958607315
2560    1.61411616  -1.214670165
2560    1.61411616  -1.494850022
2560    1.61411616  -1.823908741
2560    1.61411616  -2.22184875
2560    1.61411616  -2.698970004
2560    1.61411616  -3
2720    1.652903715 4.397940009
2720    1.652903715 3.934498451
2720    1.652903715 3.62324929
2720    1.652903715 3.491361694
2720    1.652903715 3.176091259
2720    1.652903715 2.579783597
2720    1.652903715 1.944482672
2720    1.652903715 2.146128036
2720    1.652903715 2.230448921
2720    1.652903715 2.278753601
2720    1.652903715 2.322219295
2720    1.652903715 2.230448921
2720    1.652903715 2.113943352
2720    1.652903715 2.146128036
2720    1.652903715 2.079181246
2720    1.652903715 1.977723605
2720    1.652903715 1.913813852
2720    1.652903715 1.857332496
2720    1.652903715 1.770852012
2720    1.652903715 1.662757832
2720    1.652903715 1.568201724
2720    1.652903715 1.505149978
2720    1.652903715 1.431363764
2720    1.652903715 1.322219295
2720    1.652903715 1.176091259
2720    1.652903715 1.079181246
2720    1.652903715 1
2720    1.652903715 0.937768567
2720    1.652903715 0.854609638
2720    1.652903715 0.738146089
2720    1.652903715 0.575187845
2720    1.652903715 0.362859303
2720    1.652903715 0.15896526
2720    1.652903715 -0.023191663
2720    1.652903715 -0.211831629
2720    1.652903715 -0.42945706
2720    1.652903715 -0.692503962
2720    1.652903715 -0.966576245
2720    1.652903715 -1.244125144
2720    1.652903715 -1.508638306
2720    1.652903715 -1.823908741
2720    1.652903715 -2.22184875
2720    1.652903715 -2.698970004
2720    1.652903715 -3
2880    1.661635332 2.255272505
2880    1.661635332 1.73239376
2880    1.661635332 1.977723605
2880    1.661635332 2.342422681
2880    1.661635332 2.414973348
2880    1.661635332 2.505149978
2880    1.661635332 2.414973348
2880    1.661635332 2.342422681
2880    1.661635332 2.301029996
2880    1.661635332 2.204119983
2880    1.661635332 2.113943352
2880    1.661635332 2.041392685
2880    1.661635332 1.954242509
2880    1.661635332 1.819543936
2880    1.661635332 1.672097858
2880    1.661635332 1.556302501
2880    1.661635332 1.477121255
2880    1.661635332 1.397940009
2880    1.661635332 1.301029996
2880    1.661635332 1.230448921
2880    1.661635332 1.204119983
2880    1.661635332 1.113943352
2880    1.661635332 1
2880    1.661635332 0.874075745
2880    1.661635332 0.701222484
2880    1.661635332 0.502836639
2880    1.661635332 0.302547372
2880    1.661635332 0.119255889
2880    1.661635332 -0.074687909
2880    1.661635332 -0.301899454
2880    1.661635332 -0.549750892
2880    1.661635332 -0.832682665
2880    1.661635332 -1.161150909
2880    1.661635332 -1.48148606
2880    1.661635332 -1.769551079
2880    1.661635332 -2.096910013
2880    1.661635332 -2.522878745
2880    1.661635332 -3
3040    1.584506895 2.995635195
3040    1.584506895 2.740362689
3040    1.584506895 2.924279286
3040    1.584506895 2.740362689
3040    1.584506895 2.612783857
3040    1.584506895 2.505149978
3040    1.584506895 2.505149978
3040    1.584506895 2.544068044
3040    1.584506895 2.491361694
3040    1.584506895 2.380211242
3040    1.584506895 2.322219295
3040    1.584506895 2.230448921
3040    1.584506895 2.113943352
3040    1.584506895 2.041392685
3040    1.584506895 1.954242509
3040    1.584506895 1.851258349
3040    1.584506895 1.707570176
3040    1.584506895 1.579783597
3040    1.584506895 1.477121255
3040    1.584506895 1.361727836
3040    1.584506895 1.278753601
3040    1.584506895 1.230448921
3040    1.584506895 1.230448921
3040    1.584506895 1.146128036
3040    1.584506895 1.041392685
3040    1.584506895 0.863025296
3040    1.584506895 0.629409599
3040    1.584506895 0.400710637
3040    1.584506895 0.194514342
3040    1.584506895 0.006466042
3040    1.584506895 -0.192464972
3040    1.584506895 -0.427128398
3040    1.584506895 -0.68613278
3040    1.584506895 -0.987162775
3040    1.584506895 -1.346787486
3040    1.584506895 -1.769551079
3040    1.584506895 -2.096910013
3040    1.584506895 -2.397940009
3040    1.584506895 -3
3200    1.498818328 2.929418926
3200    1.498818328 2.84509804
3200    1.498818328 2.740362689
3200    1.498818328 2.62324929
3200    1.498818328 2.544068044
3200    1.498818328 2.447158031
3200    1.498818328 2.342422681
3200    1.498818328 2.278753601
3200    1.498818328 2.255272505
3200    1.498818328 2.176091259
3200    1.498818328 2.041392685
3200    1.498818328 1.897627091
3200    1.498818328 1.826074803
3200    1.498818328 1.763427994
3200    1.498818328 1.662757832
3200    1.498818328 1.556302501
3200    1.498818328 1.447158031
3200    1.498818328 1.361727836
3200    1.498818328 1.278753601
3200    1.498818328 1.176091259
3200    1.498818328 1.113943352
3200    1.498818328 1.079181246
3200    1.498818328 1.041392685
3200    1.498818328 0.901785145
3200    1.498818328 0.677789391
3200    1.498818328 0.422425676
3200    1.498818328 0.185542155
3200    1.498818328 -0.012333735
3200    1.498818328 -0.225483034
3200    1.498818328 -0.494850022
3200    1.498818328 -0.801342913
3200    1.498818328 -1.119186408
3200    1.498818328 -1.508638306
3200    1.498818328 -2
3200    1.498818328 -2.397940009
3200    1.498818328 -2.698970004
3200    1.498818328 -3
3200    1.498818328 -3
```

Comment: This code errors with the data you provided.

Comment: ok let me post all the data then

Comment: pls the full data has been updated

Comment: Your data is the problem. You have tens of `(x,y)` data points  that correspond to several different `T` values e.g. just the first 2 rows. When you input this information into `griddata`, it chooses one of them (not sure how, or if average). The problem comes from you not understanding your data or the problem you are trying to solve, and depending on that, this can have multiple different solutions.

Comment: ok thanks, but pls what do you think i do, when i change the columns the T data is shown